# Use python bindings to clang to check if a C++ type is a pointer, reference, etc. in canonical fashion?

Tags: python, c++, clang, llvm-clang

Consider an object `t` of type `clang.cindex.Type` representing a C++ variable declaration such as `const T& x;` or a parameter declaration occurring in something like

```
template<typename... Ts> void f(Ts&&...);
```

Is there a *canonical* way to determine if `t` is/represents (1) a pointer, (2) a lvalue or rvalue reference, (3) a parameter pack?

Obviously, by manually parsing `t.spelling`, one can solve the above problems, roughly as follows: Assume that the file `x.h` contains

```
const T & x;
```

Then the following code will print `True`:

```py
import clang
from clang import cindex

def is_lvalue_ref(type):
    spell = type.spelling  # 'const T &'
    tokens = spell.split(' ')  # ['const', 'T', '&']
    return (tokens[-1] == '&') 
cindex.Config.set_library_path('/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib')
index = cindex.Index.create()
tu = index.parse('x.h', ['c++', '-std=c++17'])
for x in tu.cursor.get_children():
    # x is CursorKind.VAR_DECL
    print(is_lvalue_ref(x.type))
```

(For pointers or parameter packs, proceed similarly.)
But clearly, this is undesirable! Is there a canonical way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think i'm super late right now, but i had the same problem and solved in a canonical way.

Whenever you have a `PARM_DECL` you can understand if some qualifier is applied in this way:

```
node.type.get_pointee().is_const_qualified()
```

It returns True if the parameter declaration has the `const` qualifier, like:

```
const string &
```

EDIT:

I have finally found the solution: once you have a `typekind` object you just access the attribute `kind` and if it is a reference its kind will be TypeKind.LVALUEREFERENCE.

```
node.type.kind
```

If you want to access the underlying type of the reference you need to get it through get_pointee(), so

```
node.type.get_pointee().spelling
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question was: How to check if `t` is a reference, etc... :) Also, I haven't checked this thoroughly, but this doesn't seem to work with variadic template parameters. If `const T& x` is replaced with `template<typename... T> void f(const T&...);`, then applying your method to the `PARM_DECL` returns negative.

Comment: The `PARM_DECL` in `template<typename... T> void f(const T&...);` has type `TypeKind.UNEXPOSED`, so your solution doesn't work there.